# How to remove NaNs in aws redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to remove NaNs from a column in aws redshift (based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2).

I would like to use an update statement to do this, for example:

```
UPDATE table001
SET variable_a = NULL
FROM table001 
WHERE variable_a = 'NaN'
```

But can't find a way to subset to the rows that I need. I have tried also `WHERE variable_a = 'NaN'::float` and `WHERE variable_a = FLOAT8 'NaN'` but in all cases the where clause doesn't bring back any rows

(variable_a has data_type float8)

Comment: Just curious. Could you check: `SELECT * FROM table001 WHERE NOT (variable_1 <> 'NaN')`? Plus probably some `NULL` handling if column is nullable.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I tried this but it brings back zero rows though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to another `NaN` in RedShift columns (unlike PostgreSQL).

You should check for its text representation:

```
UPDATE  table001
SET     variable_a = NULL
WHERE   variable_a::TEXT = 'nan' -- mind the case
```

Comment: Using `WHERE   variable_a::TEXT = 'NaN'` in the where clause works as expected, thanks